# Is "for a while" equal to "in a while"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article about Apple's products, and at the part describing this years rumor to upcomming new laptop computers it went "a major upgrade has been due for a while"

I'm not sure if I took the meaning of "for a while" correctly. Does this means "in a while", "in the near future" or "in the immediate future"?

The above phrases is extracted from "Report: New ultra-thin MacBooks coming later in 2016, featuring new metal-injection molded hinges"

http://9to5mac.com/2016/04/15/report-new-ultra-thin-macbooks-coming-later-in-2016-featuring-new-metal-injection-molded-hinges/

Thank you for the help as always!

Comment: The sense of the sentence is "We have been expecting for some time [probably for the past several months, but perhaps even longer] that Apple will be releasing a major upgrade to its laptop computers."

Answer (score 1):

**No**, they do not mean *exactly* the same. It is mainly the usage that separates the two.

**In a while** is rather used when an action is negated as in "I haven't been running in a while"

**For a while** is rather used when an action is/has been ongoing e.g. "I have been running for a while this morning"

However, both are somewhat interchangable to some degree.

EDIT: This question is a duplicate, please see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113797/148613)

Comment: I become aware of some difference between “for a while” and “in a while”. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. They are not the same. 
**For a while** is used to talk about something that has been going on for sometime, or something that will take a certain amount of time in the future, or something that you did for a definite time in the past.
**In a while** is always used for future events, to talk about things you will be doing, or will be completing, in the future. Regardless, the event is in the future.
In this context, the meaning is that the update has been due for some time, but it has not been done. It is an incomplete action that was expected to be completed in the past.

Comment: I'll be there in a while. This indicates a future event. On the other hand, “I’ll be there for a while” means an ongoing event. My understanding at present is like this. Thank you for the help any way!